# Sending a synchronous signal/message to a long running PHP script

Tags: php, signals, systemd

I have a long running PHP script that I'm attempting to convert into a `systemd` daemon.

While planing the daemon, I figured that I could simply send SITERM/SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2/etc. signals to restart/reload to my script when necessary using the `kill` command, but after reading through the `systemd` documentation, I've noticed [this bit in the "ExecReload" section](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecReload=):

> Note however that reloading a daemon by sending a signal (as with the example line above) is usually not a good choice, because this is an asynchronous operation and hence not suitable to order reloads of multiple services against each other. It is strongly recommended to set `ExecReload=` to a command that not only triggers a configuration reload of the daemon, but also synchronously waits for it to complete.

So, while my script will run just fine and the daemon itself will work properly using `kill` to signal various events (I don't have and most likely won't ever have another daemon that would depend on this one), the quote above got me thinking about alternatives of sending a synchronous message to the daemon.

The only thing that I could think of so far is:

1. Open a local socket in the daemon and listen for messages on it
2. Execute any supported action when receiving a message
3. Send an `OK` message back to the sender once the action is complete

Is there a better/recommended/optimal way of achieving this?